# React-select onChange trigger when user select same option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

The onChange of a [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) drop down is getting triggered when I select an already selected value in the drop down. Is there a way to configure react-select to not trigger onChange event if already selected value is selected again.

```
  handleOnChange(value) {
    console.log("test");
    this.setState({ multiValue: value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select.Creatable
          options={this.state.options}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.multiValue}
          showNewOptionAtTop={false}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

As you can see the console log calling even if the value is the same. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-forked-1me8b)

Comment: Please try to useEffect()([]) function.

Comment: @ArtemMedianyk why?

Comment: useEffect will run only if the value changed. When you select an already selected value in the drop down, it will not run the code in useEffect()

Comment: And bind function should be defined in constructor().

Comment: @ArtemMedianyk I think you don't understand the question. Even if I use `useEffect` it will trigger twice. Problem is how to solve it? `useEffect` is not the cure in this situation.

Comment: Oh, I see. BTW, what do  you mean by trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the value on onChange of react select.

I changed your onChange function with arrow function:

```
onChange={value => {
    if (value !== this.state.multiValue){
       this.handleOnChange(value);
    }
}}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-forked-fvzgh?file=/index.js:687-826)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can disable the change event but as a workaround You can simply hold the current value of the selected item and return from the change handler if the selected item was the previous one like [@ahmetkilinc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7688423/ahmetkilinc) answer, also menu items have an option

```
isDisabled
```

that you can change to true when one item is selected, therefore it can't be selected anymore.